# Pass javascript variable to apex variable , error : cannot set value of null

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

Apex controller :

```
public class NameController {
    public String acname {get;set;} 
    private final Account acct;
    public NameController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        acname = 'temp';
    }
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Information" columns="1" showHeader="false" collapsible="true" >

        <apex:form >
            <apex:inputHidden id="hdnField" value="{!acname}" />

        </apex:form>                    
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

<script>
    var v = encodeURIComponent("{!Account.Name}");
     console.debug(document.getElementById("{!$Component.hdnField}"));
    var x = document.getElementById("{!$Component.hdnField}");
    x.value = v; // I am getting error here
</script>
```

Comment: Are you passing the Account Id in url ?

Comment: yes , i want to pass the encoded account name

Comment: you can simply get the account name in controller using standard controller.. `this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord(); system.debug('======='+acct.Name);`

Comment: I need encoded value not the original value

Answer (score 2):

Directly addressing the problem in the page as posted, the [$Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm) documentation rather vaguely says:

> If your component is nested, you might need to use a more complete
>   component path specifier.

You can check what HTML Visualforce generates by using your browser's "View Source" on the resulting page to check that the `$Component` reference is "complete" and so generates a valid Id that is present in the HTML.

For your case adding the full path like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" id="p">
<apex:pageBlock id="pb">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Information" columns="1" showHeader="false" collapsible="true" id="pbs">

        <apex:form id="f">
            <apex:inputHidden id="hdnField" value="{!Account.Name}" />

        </apex:form>                    
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

<script>
    var v = encodeURIComponent("{!Account.Name}");
     console.debug(document.getElementById("{!$Component.p.pb.pbs.f.hdnField}"));
    var x = document.getElementById("{!$Component.p.pb.pbs.f.hdnField}");
    x.value = v; // I am getting error here
</script>
</apex:page>
```

works with this result visible via "View Source":

```
var x = document.getElementById("p:pb:pbs:f:hdnField");
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck using the `ends with` selector:

```
document.querySelector("[id$='hdnField']").value
```

Or better yet, use style classes:

```
<apex:inputHidden styleClass="hdnField" ... />

<script>
      var inputValue = document.getElementsByClassName('hdnField')[0].value;
 </script>
```

---

As for why what you have doesn't work, you have to reference all the parent tags as well. If they don't have `id` attributes specified, it's more of a pain and not worth the trouble in my opinion, hence the above recommendations. Have a look at the `Visualforce Developer Guide` (emphasis mine):

> ## [Using $Component to Reference Components from JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_access.htm)
>
> Use the `$Component` global variable to simplify referencing the DOM ID that is generated for a Visualforce component, and reduce some of the dependency on the overall page structure.
>
> Every Visualforce tag has an id attribute. The id attribute for a tag can be used by another tag to bind the two tags together. For example, the `<apex:outputLabel>` tag’s for attribute can be used with the `<apex:inputField>` tag’s id attribute. The reRender and status attributes on , `<apex:actionSupport>`, and other action-oriented components also use the value of the id attribute from other components.
>
> In addition to being used to bind Visualforce components together, this ID is used to form part of the document object model (DOM) ID for the component when the page is rendered.
>
> **To refer to a Visualforce component in JavaScript or another Web-enabled language, you must specify a value for the id attribute for that component. A DOM ID is constructed from a combination of the id attribute of the component and the id attributes of all components that contain the element.**

See also:

> ## [Best Practices for Accessing Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)
>
> To refer to a Visualforce component in JavaScript or another Web-enabled language, you must specify a value for the id attribute for that component. A DOM ID is constructed from a combination of the id attribute of the component and the id attributes of all components that contain the element.
>
> Use the `$Component` global variable to simplify referencing the DOM ID that is generated for a Visualforce component, and reduce some of the dependency on the overall page structure. To reference a specific Visualforce component’s DOM ID, add a component path specifier to `$Component`, using dot notation to separate each level in the component hierarchy of the page. For example, use `$Component.itemId` to reference a component at the same level in the Visualforce component hierarchy, or use `$Component.grandparentId.parentId.itemId` to specify a more complete component path.
>
> A `$Component` path specifier is matched against the component hierarchy:
>   At the current level of the component hierarchy where `$Component` is used; and then
>   At each successive higher level in the component hierarchy, until a match is found, or the top-level of the component hierarchy is reached.